# Find missing hours and minutes in List

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I would like to find missing timeranges in List.
Event has StartDate and EndDate (with time). I will have same Day/Month/Year in that list, so only time is different in every object. Let's say that every event is on 01-01-2016 then times looks like that:

- Start: 07:00 End: 09:00
- Start: 09:00 End: 11:30
- Start: 13:00 End: 14:00
- Start: 18:15 End: 20:00

I would like to find free hours in that list, so I would like to get something like that

- Start: 11:30 End: 13:00
- Start: 14:00 End: 18:15

How can I get something like that?

Comment: looks pretty straight forward to me.. if the list should flow withing a 2 hour differential then if you find a value that has a 1 hour difference then you should know what's missing.. start writing some code and show us at the very least what you have tried on your own.. also read up on the `Hour` property within the DateTime Struct.. do a google search as well on TimeSpan as well good luck

Comment: What about `00:00 -> 07:00` and `20:00 -> 24:00`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't have to look for that hours, because event can start at 07:00 or later and end at 20:00 or earlier.

Comment: Just iterate through your list comparing the end time of the current entry to the start time of the next - if they are not the same then create a new entry in your free hours list starting at the current end time & finishing at the next start time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following, this assumes the times are in order

```
var today = DateTime.UtcNow;

var bookedTimes = new[]
{
    new DateRange(new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 07, 00, 00),
        new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 09, 00, 00)),
    new DateRange(new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 09, 00, 00),
        new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 11, 00, 00)),
    new DateRange(new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 13, 00, 00),
        new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 14, 00, 00)),
    new DateRange(new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 18, 00, 00),
        new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 20, 00, 00)),
};

var freeTimes = new List<DateRange>();
for (var i = 0; i < bookedTimes.Length -1; i++)
{
    var current = bookedTimes[i];
    var next = bookedTimes[i + 1];

    if (current.To != next.From)
    {
        var range = new DateRange(current.To, next.From);
        freeTimes.Add(range);
    }
}

foreach (var time in freeTimes)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"From {time.From.ToShortTimeString()}, to: {time.To.ToShortTimeString()}");
}

// Outputs:
// From 11:00, to: 13:00
// From 14:00, to: 18:00
```

Comment: Great. Just thought there is a function or method which I could use after dot, but seems it has to be written by ourselves. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Linq Zip method to join the list to itself 1 entry apart creating a gap list & then filter out the entries where the start & end times are the same.

```
var gaplist =
      eventlist.Zip(eventlist.Skip(1), (ev1, ev2) => new MyEvent(ev1.End, ev1.Start))
                 .Where(gp => gp.Start != gp.End)
                 .ToList();
```